# Limit point of a subset of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

p is a limit point of a subset of real numbers(say S) iff every neighborhood of p contains infinitely many points of S.

How do I prove the direct part?

Well I know the idea.Let us consider a neighborhood of p which contains finitely many points of S.Then I consider the distance between each of these points and p and take epsilon to be the minimum of these distances.Our claim is this epsilon symmetric neighborhood of p has no points of S.But how do we show it?In many textbooks which I have seen I see it has been written directly without proving that this neighborhood has no points of S.Even though this seems obvious how do I show it?

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $P$ and there are only finitely many points of $S$ say $$x_1,x_2, ...,x_n$$  in $U$

Consider the set of distances from the point $P$ to points $x_1,x_2,..., x_n $ that is $$ d(p,x_1), d(P,x_2),..., d(P,x_n)$$

Let $$\epsilon = 1/2 \min \{d(P,x_1), d(P,x_2),..., d(P,x_n)\}$$

Now the open ball centered at $P$ and radius $\epsilon$  $$V=B(P,\epsilon)$$ does not include any point of $S$ because the distance from $P$ to any point of $S$ is larger than $\epsilon$

Comment: But how do I know that there is no point of S within epsilon range?

Comment: @Shash The distance from $P$ to any $x_i$, $i=1,2,..,n$ is larger than $ \epsilon$ so they are all outside the $V$